# How to add and modify the menu button using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm kind of lost with this functionality. I already scrapped the web but I don't find anything helpful. I want to display and modify the menu button ([Menu Button](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#menu-button)) using python-telegram-bot ([PTB set_chat_menu_button](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.set_chat_menu_button)). I tried the following line when initializing the bot but nothing happens

```
await context.bot.set_chat_menu_button(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
        menu_button=MenuButton(MenuButtonCommands)
    )
```

Comment: This could be a caching issue on your clients side. Please try restarting the Telegram client/the device or logging in on a different client/device.